# I have an authentification failed error when i try to push with GitHub desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

im a beginner so i tried to use Git/GitHub, i downloaded the GitHub desktop but when i want to push my project i have an authentification failed.

i tried to use the personnal access token like it is specified on the website but it didnt work. I also tried to uninstall and re-install GitHub desktop, logout and re-login.

I dont have the 2FA enabled (i saw it might be the problem)

Do you have any ideas, i saw plenty of solutions on the web but im a beginner then i didnt understand everything

Comment: First, what's your OS? More importantly, are you using your Personal Access Token to connect? Your password won't work, you need to use your PAT.

Comment: Note that Git and GitHub are different (though related: GitHub is a *hosting site* on which you can store Git repositories; they add a lot of features that aren't in base Git to attract users so as to make GitHub itself more valuable due to the [network effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect). In this particular case—authentication—you're right on the edge between a Git thing and a GitHub thing. Git doesn't do any authentication on its own, but does know of "credential helpers" to use with https, and will run ssh (which does its own separate authentication) when using ssh.

Comment: So, in this case, you'll need *first* to see whether your `git push` action is using https or ssh. If it's using https, you'll then need to see which credential helpers are available for your OS and which of those you should use (almost certainly there's at least one you can use here). Last, let me add that *GitHub Desktop* is yet a *third* thing: neither Git nor GItHub, it's a [GUI provided by the GitHub folks](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop) that, they think, makes it easier to use Git and GItHub. (I think it makes it harder, but I have a general anti-GUI bias  )

Comment: @joanis i'm using windows, when i tried to use the PAT i used the token as password and my email as login

Comment: @torek first of all i tried with git bash and when i tried to push i had the authentification error then i installed GitHub desktop and i had the same error

Comment: See [ask]. We need to know the relevant details (we don't need irrelevant ones, but as a beginner you won't know which ones are relevant, unfortunately). See also [mre]: if you have an example set of steps to reproduce the problem, that helps someone help you.